# cxf merlindevice configuration

Tags: java, cxf

I need to sign web service soap message body and timestamp via smart card.

I am using cxf 2.7.12. In cxf ugly documentation, they say "MerlinDevice: Based on Merlin, allows loading of keystores using a null InputStream - for example on a smart-card device". But no example or documentation is provided.

Is there anybody who can provide a cofiguration of merlindevice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved the problem.

1. Create a class e.g. PKCS11Device extending Merlin
2. Copy MerlinDevice source in it
3. Copy Merlin load method in it
4. Change first lines of load method as

   ```
   public KeyStore load(InputStream input, String storepass, String provider, 
   String type) 
   throws CredentialException {

   KeyStore ks = null;

   SunPKCS11 akisProvider = new SunPKCS11("pkcs.properties");
   Security.addProvider(akisProvider);

   try {
       if (provider == null || provider.length() == 0) {
           ks = KeyStore.getInstance(type);
       } else {
           //ks = KeyStore.getInstance(type, provider);
           ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11",akisProvider);
       }
   ```

   ...............
5. Repackage wss4j.jar
6. Replace the new jar with the old one in cxf lib folder.

   -----In your project
7. Create your card specific pkcs.properties

mine was

```
name = AKIS
library = C:/windows/system32/akisp11.dll
disabledMechanisms={ CKM_SHA1_RSA_PKCS }
```

1. Make your wss4j.properties file as

   ```
   org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider=org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.PKCS11Device      
   org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.provider=SunPKCS11
   org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type=PKCS11
   org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password=xxxxx
   ```

And it works!

Answer (score 1):

See here for some documentation: http://ws.apache.org/wss4j/config.html

The actual properties file will look almost identical to the standard one used for "Merlin", except that the provider will be called "MerlinDevice" instead:

https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cxf.git;a=blob_plain;f=systests/ws-security-examples/src/test/resources/alice.properties;hb=HEAD

Colm.

Comment: Hi Colm. Your succession is common in the web including wss4j and cxf documentation. When you change the line with org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider=org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.MerlinDevice the error java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.MerlinDevice.<init> comes. Actualy, Merlin has method for getPrivateKey but you cannot get private key from smart card. That is the problem I think. And in configuration one must pass the native smart-card lib. to device, but there is no example of how.

Comment: What is the full stacktrace you are seeing? Also, what version of WSS4J?

Comment: I am using V 1.6.16 of WSS4J. And the stack trace is:Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: class org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.MerlinDevice cannot create instance
 at org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.CryptoFactory.loadClass(CryptoFactory.java:242)
 at org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.CryptoFactory.getInstance(CryptoFactory.java:135)
 at org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.CryptoFactory.getInstance(CryptoFactory.java:187)

Comment: at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.AbstractWSS4JInterceptor.loadCryptoFromPropertiesFile(AbstractWSS4JInterceptor.java:224)
 at org.apache.ws.security.handler.WSHandler.loadCrypto(WSHandler.java:910)
 at org.apache.ws.security.handler.WSHandler.loadSignatureCrypto(WSHandler.java:823)
 at org.apache.ws.security.handler.WSHandler.doSenderAction(WSHandler.java:143)
 at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor.access$200(WSS4JOutInterceptor.java:52)
 at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor$WSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(WSS4JOutInterceptor.java:265)
 ... 10

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.MerlinDevice.<init>(java.util.Properties, java.lang.ClassLoader)
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3069)
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1812)
 at org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.CryptoFactory.loadClass(CryptoFactory.java:236)
 ... 18 more

Comment: I had to devide the full stack trace to 3 parts. If you add a constructor `public MerlinDevice(boolean loadCACerts, String cacertsPasswd)` a different error comes.

Comment: It's a bug in WSS4J which I've just fixed: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1620851

Comment: Thank you Colm. You saved our dates and nigths. In the link above there is a line org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file=keys/x509.PFX.MSFT but if you are using a usb stick e-sign device for example, you dont have such a file and you cannot get the private key from device. In addition in the documentation I did not see native lib configuration such as libpkcs11wrapper64.dll or a sign api configuration provided by third parties. Is there a way to do this or I have to dive in wss4j code to provide my own?